# Android:unable to get data from webservice using kSoap

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

hi in my app i am trying to check the username and password in database from webservice and if its true will show success message or failed message, but unable to show the status message

```
public class AndroidLoginExampleActivity extends Activity {
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.userlogin.com";
    private final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/Androidlogin/services/Login?wsdl";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.userlogin.com/authentication";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                loginAction();

            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") private void loginAction(){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
        String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
        EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
        String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

      //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
        PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
        unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
        unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
        unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
        request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

      //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
        PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
        passwordProp.setName("password");
        passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
        passwordProp.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(passwordProp);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try{
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
               SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

               TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
               result.setText(response.toString());
          Log.d("resp:",response.toString() );
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
       }
```

below is my webservice call

```
public class Login {
 public String authentication(String userName,String password){

  String retrievedUserName = "";
  String retrievedPassword = "";
  String status = "";
  try{

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","root");
   PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '"+userName+"'");
   ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

   while(result.next()){
    retrievedUserName = result.getString("username");
    retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
    }

   if(retrievedUserName.equals(userName)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password)){
    status = "Success!";
   }

   else{
    status = "Login fail!!!";
   }

  }
  catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return status;

 }

}
```

not sure were iam doing wrong.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should do network related operation on a thread. use a thread or asynctask. does your app crash?

Comment: @Radhunandan my app doesnot crash..its running..wen i give login details its not showing any status message

Comment: i suggest you use a thread or asynctask.

Comment: @Raghunandan can u suggest any example for that

Comment: here is a good example  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 1):

You should do network realted operation on a thread. You can use a `thread` or `AsyncTask`.

Move your  `loginAction()` inside a `thread` or inside `doInbackground` of `AsyncTask`.

Remember not to update ui from the back ground thread.

```
   new TheTask().execute();
```

AsyncTask

```
public class TheTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>
{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
            // display a dialog
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
              // your login authentcation 
              // remove updation of textview.
              // do not update ui here 
    return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
           // dismiss the dialog
           // update textview
          }
    }
```

AsyncTask docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.userlogin.com";
    private final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/Androidlogin/services/Login?wsdl";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.userlogin.com/authentication";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText ed1,ed2;
    TextView tv;
    String user_Name,user_Password;
    SoapPrimitive response ;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        user_Name = ed1.getText().toString();
       user_Password = ed2.getText().toString();
       pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new TheTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }
     class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,SoapPrimitive>
     {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected SoapPrimitive doInBackground(Void... params) {
               SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
                    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
                    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
                    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
                    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable
                    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
                    passwordProp.setName("password");
                    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
                    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
                    request.addProperty(passwordProp);

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    try{
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.bodyIn;
                        Log.i("Response",""+response);
                       // response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){

                    }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SoapPrimitive result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();
            if(result!=null)
            tv.setText(result.toString());
        }

     }

}
```

Comment: @Radhunandan  i did it using thread..plz see my answer below. even now itz not working

Comment: you are doing it wrong. check my edit. i am not sure about your response. but you should definitely use a thread or asynctask

Comment: oh ill try the asyncTask and let u know

Comment: @teekib check the edit modify accordingly. makes sure your soapmethods and urls are right. it will work

Comment: @teekib is your url right http://localhost:8080/Androidlogin/services/Login?wsdl. does it open in your browser? its a local host

Comment: yeahh iam running it on tomacatserver and its running.. i posted the asynctask answer please check below still not working

Comment: @teekib still wrong. check my edited part of my answer and delete your answers coz its a question rather than an answer

Comment: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /Androidlogin/services/Login and the WSA Action = null

Comment: @teekib i am not sure about it. something wrong on the server side. however the client part android part is fine as far as i know

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static String ValidateSalesOfficerLogin(Context c, String userName,
                    String passWord) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
                String METHOD_NAME = "ValidateSalesOfficerLogin";
                String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/authentication/";
                SOAP_ACTION = SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME;
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(CommonVariable.NAMESPACE,
                        METHOD_NAME);
                // Use this to add parameters
                request.addProperty("Username", userName);
                request.addProperty("Password", passWord);

                // Declare the version of the SOAP request
                return WebCalls.call(c, request, CommonVariable.NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME,
                        SOAP_ACTION);
            }



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static String call(Context c,SoapObject request ,String NAMESPACE,String METHOD_NAME,String SOAP_ACTION) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException{
            Log.i(WebCalls,"URL: "+ CommonVariable.URL);
            Log.i(WebCalls,"Method Name: "+ METHOD_NAME);
            Log.i(WebCalls,"Parameters: "+request.toString());
            String SoapResult = null;
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            envelope.dotNet = true;

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(CommonVariable.URL);

                // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
                    SoapResult = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
                } else {
                    SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    SoapResult = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString();
                }


                Log.i(WebCalls,"Response: "+ SoapResult);
            return SoapResult;
        }


call above method....

    public static void Setusernamepassword(Context context, String user ,string pass)
            throws JSONException, IOException, XmlPullParserException {

        String Response = SoaplCalls.ValidateSalesOfficerLogin(context, user,pass);
        Log.i("SetTokenId", Response);

    }




/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Setusernamepassword(viewCompetitor,user,pass);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });
                }

            }

        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: Firstly I cant understand "http://tempuri.org" why we use this and SoapEnvelope.VER11 what is this and lastly what is SOAP_ACTION....