# Connection error with KSOAP

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I have a problem, I'm using the library `Ksoap2` for my web service. But, when I run it in my emulator, the app works fine, but, when I install it on my device, I have this error:

```
null http../service.asmx
```

I have tried it in a tablet and Samsung Skyrocket.

Could someone tell me what's the problem here, please?

On my server is IIS in Win7, but when I open it in Chrhme from my mobile device, the web service works too.

```
private static final String accionSoap="http://tempuri.org/saludo";
private static final String Metodo="saludo";
private static final String namespace="http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String url="http://192.168.0.11:6060/Service.asmx";


TextView tv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    conectar();

}


private void conectar() {
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtinfo);
    try{

        SoapObject request=new SoapObject(namespace,Metodo);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre= new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sobre.implicitTypes=true;
        sobre.dotNet=true;
        sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transporte=new HttpTransportSE(url);
        transporte.call(accionSoap, sobre);

        SoapPrimitive resultado=(SoapPrimitive)sobre.getResponse();

        tv.setText(resultado.toString());



    }
    catch(Exception e){
        tv.setText("ERROR"+" "+e.getMessage()+" "+url);

    }

}
```

Comment: please paste the logcat.

Comment: are you sure that the service URL is reachable from your handset ? are you connected to the same network where you have deployed your service ? if not all you need to do is check the service URL

Comment: looks like you are doing network related operation on the ui thread

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288128/androidunable-to-get-data-from-webservice-using-ksoap/18288249#18288249. use asynctask